# Ways to charge a VERY LARGE capacitor in a 3-phase bridge rectifier circuit

Tags: three-phase, bridge-rectifier, inrush-current

I need to charge two 1500uF-450V capacitors off of a 3-phase 220Vrms-60Hz line using a very robust bridge rectifier ([datasheet](https://www.tme.com/Document/453b8af76ec8ac5f2ed2abd15fe8a652/MDS500.pdf)) as well as both capacitors datasheet ([datasheet](https://www.mouser.com/datasheet/2/136/B43740__B43760-80122.pdf)).
[image: capacitor info highlighted in yellow]

Here's the simulation I performed taking into account ESR of approx \$63\,m\Omega\$ for each cap.

[image: simulation]

**WITHOUT** the inrush limiting resistor \$R_2\$, the inrush current peaks \$4.2\,kA\$ in one of the diodes (the max forward surge for each diode is \$7500 A\$ for \$10\,ms\$) and \$1.5\,kA\$ at each capacitor. The duration of both surges is approx 1ms.

The problem is I don't think this kind of surge is good for long-term in the circuit since it might cause tripping of breakers, and it's a very large current so I'm taking the safe path and trying to limit it with an inrush resistor.

The crux of the problem is how to properly design/choose both bypass switches S1 and S2.
S1 bypasses the inrush resistor while S2 connects the load R3 to the DC voltage after reaching a reasonably okayish value (200 - 250 V).

I've looked up some solid state relays but most are rated for 40VDC max so it'd not help.
Using an IGBT for both switches I think would suffice in my POV however I don't have the time to come up with a PCB or any other additional circuitry at the moment so an off-the-shelf solution would be best here.

Any thoughts on how could I approach that with available solutions?

Comment: On the left side of your drawing, is that *Neutral*? If yes, it is tied to ground somewhere. Your circuit is also referenced to ground. D2/D4/D6 will be directly across the line, big boom.

Comment: @Mattman944 Circuit ground is arbitrary, and this is a fine reference point for simulation purposes.

Comment: It sounds like you need an inrush current limiter element, or circuit, or capacitor precharge.  This is an interesting design exercise, but it sounds like you might not have much design time available; and keep in mind asking for off-the-shelf solutions is discouraged here.

Comment: What are the specs for "charging"?

Comment: @Mattman944 No, it's not neutral. That GND is just for ease of simulation so I could measure voltages with respect to load ground. In the real-world application I won't have a neutral.

Comment: @TimWilliams yes I've been looking for a solution to get it done in a way not to spend a lot of money and fast enough. I found an old and spare DC relay which might do the business as I expect. Clearly not the best option, but in a not so far ahead future I'll use a SCR as the switch which might be the best solution to that. What do you think?

Comment: @Antonio51 400VDC and the time it takes to charge doesn't actually matter, it can even reach 5 min, it's fine. The point is preventing a high inrush current and making sure the switches are properly designed to last since many test will be carried out using that setup.

Answer (score 2):

The classic lossless alternative to resistors is to use an inductor to limit the inrush current.  You see these used extensively in switchable power factor correction capacitor banks, and you can even get PFC caps where the inductors are built into the three phase capacitor case.  This may or may not give you the desired behaviour in your rectifier circuit.

You could also consider using NTC thermistors to limit the initial inrush current.  Whether this works will depend on how quickly the load can be switched off and on again (so whether they get to cool down).

Comment: I came across the NTC thermistor idea and might do well. I have an 70A rated inductor which might help in reducing the inrush but its inductance might not suit the circuit so that'd lead to me spending money which I'm kinda out of at the moment for the project. For future ideas though, that's clearly a nice way to go.

Answer (score 2):

Classics is to use inductors for limiting inrush fire currents.

Here is a simulation with 1 mH inductors. RR = 1 Ohm ...

Crest currents should be lower than 250 A for 10 ms.
Note the high "power" for resistors.

[image]